# How do I query RDL XML data using exist and contains?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, xpath, xquery

**Problem:** 
I followed a [tutorial](http://bretstateham.com/extracting-ssrs-report-rdl-xml-from-the-reportserver-database/) on how to query the ReportServer database (SQL Server Reporting Services) to return XML results. The last line in my TSQL isn't evaluating true when I know it should be.

The WHERE clause is supposed to check the ContextXML node's text for the word "Select." I know "Select" is in the text, yet the WHERE clause isn't evaluating true.

Here's my query (**the last line is the problem**):

```
--The first CTE gets the content as a varbinary(max)
--as well as the other important columns for all reports,
--data sources and shared datasets.
WITH ItemContentBinaries AS
(
  SELECT
     ItemID,Name,[Type]
    ,CASE Type
       WHEN 2 THEN 'Report'
       WHEN 5 THEN 'Data Source'
       WHEN 7 THEN 'Report Part'
       WHEN 8 THEN 'Shared Dataset'
       ELSE 'Other'
     END AS TypeDescription
    ,CONVERT(varbinary(max),Content) AS Content
  FROM ReportServer.dbo.Catalog
  WHERE Type IN (2)
  and ItemID = '19EE23BD-E752-4021-A533-7CF159D2DB7A' -- <-- This is a RDL that I know has "Select" in its CommandText node.
),
--The second CTE strips off the BOM if it exists...
ItemContentNoBOM AS
(
  SELECT
     ItemID,Name,[Type],TypeDescription
    ,CASE
       WHEN LEFT(Content,3) = 0xEFBBBF
         THEN CONVERT(varbinary(max),SUBSTRING(Content,4,LEN(Content)))
       ELSE
         Content
     END AS Content
  FROM ItemContentBinaries
)
--The old outer query is now a CTE to get the content in its xml form only...
,ItemContentXML AS
(
  SELECT
     ItemID,Name,[Type],TypeDescription
    ,CONVERT(xml,Content) AS ContentXML
 FROM ItemContentNoBOM
)
-- Now filter items having containing the word "select" in their CommandText node.
SELECT
     ItemID,
     Name,
     [Type],
     TypeDescription,
     ContentXML
FROM 
    ItemContentXML
WHERE
    ContentXML.exist('//CommandText[contains(.,"Select")]') = 1; -- <-- THE PROBLEM! This isn't evaluating to true, even though the RDL I'm querying has "Select" in its CommandText text.
```

Comment: Post example of your `ContentXML` data please